# Why are my LEGACY OPENGL colors inverted?

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, opengl-compat

A few months ago i wrote a simple code for displaying 3 polygons. Everything worked fine. Then the colors suddenly started shifting...

Im in VISUAL STUDIO 2019.

I tried:

- Repairing the VS redistributables.
- Making a new project.

Any clue?

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        /* Render here */
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        //idk what is going on
        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex2f(0.5f, 0.5f);
        glVertex2f(-0.5f, 0.5f);
        glVertex2f(-0.5f, -0.5f);
        glVertex2f(0.5f, -0.5f);
        glColor3f(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
        glEnd();
        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex2f(0.7f, 0.7f);
        glVertex2f(-0.7f, 0.7f);
        glVertex2f(-0.7f, -0.7f);
        glVertex2f(0.7f, -0.7f);
        glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        glEnd();


        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "the colors started shifting" -- But, typically the `glColor3f()` calls come before defining the vertex.

Comment: its already answered, but it is that object 1 has color 2, object 2 has color 3, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The color attribute has to be set ([`glColor`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glColor.xml)) before the vertex coordinate is specified by [`glVertex2f`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glVertex.xml):

```cpp
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    
glColor3f(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f);

glVertex2f(0.5f, 0.5f);
glVertex2f(-0.5f, 0.5f);
glVertex2f(-0.5f, -0.5f);
glVertex2f(0.5f, -0.5f);

glEnd();

glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

glVertex2f(0.7f, 0.7f);
glVertex2f(-0.7f, 0.7f);
glVertex2f(-0.7f, -0.7f);
glVertex2f(0.7f, -0.7f);

glEnd();
```

Note, `glColor` sets the current color and when `glVertex` is called, then the current color, normal and texture coordinates are associated with the vertex.